# Instafeed working fine, but causing page to be "scrollable"

Tags: javascript, css, magento

Hi there I am pretty new to this an have a weird thing happening:
I have implemented instafeed into my magento page via

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/instafeed2.phtml"}}
```

and added the code in the xml as well:

```
      <reference name="head">
       <action method="addItem">
      <type>skin_js</type>
      <name>js/instafeed/instafeed.min.js</name>
      </action> 
      </reference>
```

Th images are being pulled and displayed that is all fine, the problem is, one I add the block with the phtml info, reload the page, scrollbars appeare, and I can move the whole page very far to the right. If I remove the Instafeed, the page stays in its frame. Any ideas what can be causing this? I am tearing my hair out... Cheers & THANKS!

Comment: I figured it out, I had a div width set wrong, far too big, hence the scrolling ;O) this is correct: <div id="instagram_list" class="simply-scroll-list" style="width:1200px"> I had 4200px....

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had a div width set wrong, far too big, hence the scrolling ;O) this is correct:

I had 4200px set which was causing the problem...